# iOS 7 full-screen layout

Tags: layout, uiviewcontroller, fullscreen, ios7

It is known that in iOS 7 view controllers have full-screen layout by default and wantsFullScreenLayout is deprecetated, i do not want full-screen layout because it causes problems when compiling old apps with XCode 5, so i have tried this below.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

}
```

This does not seem to be working. And i am getting full-screen layouts. I am using XCode Developer Preview Beta 6. Any solutions?

Regards,

Can

Answer (score 2):

try to set edgesForExtendedLayout to UIExtendedEdgeNone

as explained here
[porting view controllers iOS 6->7](http://www.mobinett.com/2013/08/19/ios7-ui-transition-porting-view-controller-layouts-ios6/)

Answer (score 1):

If this doesn't work, you can try 
   self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
because navigation is translucent by default in iOS7